# Can i change the margins only for the title in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I have a long title for my MS word document. I only want to change the margin for the title not the main text on the main page. How may I do so?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

### Change the indents, not the margins.

Here is [my writing on the difference](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Margins_and_Indents). Margins are not a paragraph or page attribute but a section attribute. You do not want to add sections to change the indents on a paragraph. When you change the margin for part of a page, you add two sections to your Word document. That adds a lot of unnecessary complexity to the document file, which may lead to confusion later.

You can have paragraph indents *(which act like left and right margins)* which are different from the section margins.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot of the paragraph formatting dialog box].

You cannot set that right indent using the ruler in recent versions of Word.

Answer (score 0):

Two way for text to extend into the margins :

- Use a negative left indent for the paragraph, for it to to
  overflow over the left margin
- To overflow into the right margin, you need to use a text-box.
  This requires in *File > Options > Advanced* to uncheck
  "Automatically Create Drawing Canvas When Inserting AutoShapes".

Comment: To overflow the right margin you do not need a text box. You need to set the right indent using the paragraph dialog. I've added a screenshot to my answer.